# Need way to bind params in select via active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there any way to use bind params in rails active record method select?
I have the query like

```
SELECT column * #{param1} / #{param2} as value
FROM table
ORDER BY value
```

So there i have outer params, which i want to bind.

**Need something like**

```
Table.select('column * :param1 / :param2 as value', 
             {param1: param1, param2: param2})   
      .order('value').all
```

Error on this query
`Unsupported argument type: Hash. construct an Arel node instead.`

Comment: If you haven't yet, I strongly recommend you read the Rails Guide on the query interface. It will tell you what you need to know: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html :) It should cover how to add params to query-chunks... also have you tried what you suggest? did it fail? if so - can you tell us the error message you got?

Comment: I tried this query and tried to cover it with `[]`, but `select` don't expect this arguments. Also i sought for decision in documentation and in google, but didn't find nothing same with my issue

Comment: "can you tell us the error message you got?" :)
Also - have you tried plain string-interpolation... just to see if it works? (you don't want to keep string interpolation as it's unsafe sql, but for testing if there's something seriously wrong with your query it's a good thing to try)

Comment: @TarynEast Plain string-interpolation worked fine, error message added to question

Comment: cool, so at least we can be certain it's just that selects don't like hash-config rather than something wrong with the statement...